# HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Tags: python, php, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="",description="`Bot Latency...`",color=colour)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        times = []
        counter = 0
        embed = discord.Embed(title="More Information:", description="4 pings have been made and here are the results:", colour=colour)
        for _ in range(3):
            counter += 1
            start = time.perf_counter()
            embed.description=f"Trying Ping... {counter}/3"
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
            end = time.perf_counter()
            speed = round((end - start) * 1000)
            times.append(speed)
            if speed < 160:
                embed.add_field(name=f"Ping {counter}:", value=f" | {speed}ms", inline=True)
            elif speed > 170:
                embed.add_field(name=f"Ping {counter}:", value=f" | {speed}ms", inline=True)
            else:
                embed.add_field(name=f"Ping {counter}:", value=f" | {speed}ms", inline=True)
        embed.set_author(name="    PONG    ", icon_url="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/table-tennis.png")
        embed.add_field(name="Bot Latency", value=f"{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Normal Speed", value=f"{round((round(sum(times)) + round(bot.latency * 1000))/4)}ms")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Total estimated elapsed time: {round(sum(times))}ms")
        await msg.edit(content=f":ping_pong: **{round((round(sum(times)) + round(bot.latency * 1000))/4)}ms**", embed=embed)
```

Error: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

It was working a few days ago but suddenly it stooped working
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error with the `color` for the embed.

You can use something like this `color=discord.Color.light_gray()` or `color=discord.Color.random()`.

Keep in mind each embed will take a random color, if you don't want that then save it into a variable at the beginning and use that

[Full list of colors](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=color#discord.Colour)

Comment: I actually have a variable for the colour

Comment: Where is that? I can't see it

Comment: colour = int("{:06x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 16)

Comment: You can use [discord.Colour.random()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=color#discord.Colour.random), I edited my code to use it.

Comment: i have that in all of my commands the error is not that

Comment: I ran your code by just changing the color, try removing the color and see if it will run

Comment: i changed it and it still wont work i know other people can run it but I don't know why I can´t its not the color

Comment: Possibly that you done so many API requests you got locked, since each edit and send is a request. In this command only you can have 5 requests. Try make a new bot from dev portal and check it

Comment: maybe i think thats it

Comment: already try that, waited a couple of days, and nothing. Is it possible to get unlocked from the API?